# Can I travel to Paris with a type A multiple entry visa valid for 3 years?

Tags: schengen

Can I travel to Paris with a multiple entry visa valid for 3 years and it is type A visa? I was recently denied a Canadian visa and I need to travel for my holiday.

Comment: As explained below, the answer is almost certainly “no” but to get a precise answer you should specify (1) your citizenship (2) which journey (origin/layover/destination) you are contemplating and possibly (3) which other visa/residence permits you currently hold.

Answer (score 2):

A “type A” Schengen visa is an airport transit visa. You cannot travel *to* Paris or enter the Schengen area with it but you might be able to connect between two flights to non-Schengen destinations there. The Canadian visa might make the type A visa unnecessary but isn't directly relevant otherwise.

Also, the validity duration isn't important as such but the visa needs to be valid during the whole duration of your stay in the Schengen area and you must in any case [never stay more than 90 days in a 180-day period](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule).